# geom_rect background introduces missing values and won't plot the coloured background

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have time data for three different areas collected at the same time and I need to highlight the night data. I would like a background grey bar highligthing the night data. This is my data

```
> dput(head(gra))
 structure(list(Day = c("Day", "Day", "Night", "Night", "Day", 
 "Day"), x = 1:6, Zones = c("Zone C", "Zone C", "Zone C", "Zone C", 
 "Zone C", "Zone C"), Values = c(4.648410153, 0.187158871, -14.39132531, 
 -16.29031506, -5.211906368, 0.372469736)), .Names = c("Day", 
  "x", "Zones", "Values"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

and this is my code

```
g <- ggplot(gra, aes(x = x, y = Values)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = Zones), size = 0.5) + 
  geom_point() +
  xlim(0, 30) + 
  ylim(-50, 30) +
  scale_color_grey() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), 
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = -90, hjust = 0))

g + geom_rect(aes(xmin = as.integer(factor(Values, 
                                           levels = Values, 
                                           ordered = TRUE)) - .5,
                  xmax = as.integer(factor(Values, 
                                           levels = Values, 
                                           ordered = TRUE)) + .5,
                  ymin = -Inf, 
                  ymax = Inf, 
                  fill = Day, group = Day), 
                alpha = 0.2)
g
```

but it won't highlight the night data

Comment: Can't reproduce your error. Please edit your question with the output of `dput(gra)`. (note: I assume the missing "ordered" in `geom_rect(aes(xmax = ...))` was a typo that occurred when you pasted your code over, since it doesn't cause the error described, & corrected it during my edit)

Comment: It works on my end as well.  I imagine you are using a subset of your data here, but if a `Values` was ever repeated, this might cause errors since you are converting into a factor.  Why not just use `geom_rect(aes(xmin = x - .5,               xmax = x + .5, ...)`

Comment: Thanks, after @Z.Lin edits I don't have any errors but it still doesn't highlight the night data